# Catalina LifeCycle Exception in Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am unable to remove this error in tomcat. The error is as followed:-

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@29f69090] at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize
>   component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@29f69090]
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4758)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4893)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
>   ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>   ... 33 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening
>   zip file at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:164)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:149)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
>   ... 34 more Jul 18, 2018 5:16:20 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@ca263c2] at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize
>   component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@ca263c2] at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4758)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4893)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
>   ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>   ... 33 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening
>   zip file at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:164)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:149)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
>   ... 34 more Jul 18, 2018 5:16:20 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@45f45fa1] at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize
>   component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@45f45fa1]
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4758)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4893)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
>   ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>   ... 33 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening
>   zip file at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:164)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:149)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
>   ... 34 more Jul 18, 2018 5:16:20 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
>   ... 13 more Jul 18, 2018 5:16:20 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start SEVERE: The required Server
>   component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

Please let me know how to resolve Lifecycle Exception in tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file at

Seems that tomcat is not able to open your WAR file. Can you make sure the contents of your WAR file and also the WAR file itself if not corrupt. Try opening it with WINRAR and see if indeed the archive structure is correct.